Double Color in Three Js Buffer Geomtery shapes
I am using three.js to create shapes, but while drawing my irregular polygon shapes face double coloring using while drawing from certain directions. Example: I attached two pictures of same shapes, while one drawn from right side will be good but the one drawn from left will create a double color effect. How can I fix this?
Here is the image of shape with double color problem; the yellow height shows double color issue

Here the code of generating the shapes
let polyShape = new THREE.Shape(coordinates.map((coord) => new THREE.Vector2(coord.x, coord.y)))
const polyGeometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(polyShape);
polyGeometry.setAttribute("position", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(coordinates.map(coord => [coord.x, coord.y, coord.z]).flat(), 3))
let polygon = new THREE.Mesh(polyGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "white",side: THREE.DoubleSide, opacity:0.05, transparent:true,depthTest:false}))

I want that drawing from any direction won't cause such problem.
